# Get EMV Card Data Tag '9F53'

Tags: java, emv

I'm looking for EMV Tag value.

All the rest of the data needed was taken from the card reader.

However, tag value '9F53' could not be obtained.
I'm asking you this question because Google doesn't find a formula or a way to get it.

If you know a solution, please help.

Comment: Hello! Could you please add a little more details about your setup and what you have tried so far?

Comment: I use a card reader from China to program it to make payments can be possible. The value of 9F53 tag value is not available to the manufacturer using SDK or Sample Code.

Comment: If you mean Transaction Category Code you will have to look into the MasterCard specifications which are not public.

Answer (score 4):

Tag 0x9F53 is customized by payment card specifications. It may have different meaning and values.

For example it can be:

- Consecutive Transaction Counter International Limit (CTCIL) in Visa VIS, Amex AEIPS, UnionPay UICC.
- Transaction Category Code in EMV Contactless Kernel 2 used by MasterCard PayPass.
- Dynamic Terminal Interchange Profile in EMV Contactless Kernel 5 used by JCB J/Speedy.
- Contactless Card Verification Results (CVR) in EMV Contactless Kernel 6 used by Diners/Discover Contactless D-PAS.